# 3D Printing - Cylinder printing has holes - why? How to print with internal supports - Ultimaker Cura

Tags: blender

Blender and 3D printing beginner here.

First of all I'm using Ultimaker Cura and Blender of course, with an Ender 3 Pro to print.

I need to print this cylinder with extruded paths. How do I go about it? I'm struggling to set the printer to support the structure internally. The blue on this image is an external support. The grey parts at the top of the half cylinder laying down is just absent of filament, so when I print this it gets to this point and basically breaks.

So how can I fix this? I used a solidify modifier in Blender but it doesn't seem to make a difference if I do or don't..

Any help would be much appreciated
[image]

Comment: Have you tried printing this in the position that's in the bottom right? It's possible your overhangs won't work, but the rest should print just fine.

Comment: Blender tends to have inverted surfaces. It appears that the outer shell is pretty much "inside out" - what for blender doesn't matter, is crucial for Cura.

Comment: @Trish that's the solution, many questions similar to this one have been caused by Blender. Didn't you wrote a previous elaborate answer? Maybe we could link it here, or possibly flag for duplicate.

Comment: https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/15881/8884 & https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/14525/8884

Comment: please [edit] the question with a picture of the preview of the models, as that shows what might lead to the errors you are seeing to the knowing eye. Another way would be to share the model so others can inspect it.